# Is this noise normal when PC shuts down?

Tags: motherboard, shutdown

I am not an expert but since I replaced motherboard (for CPU upgrade) I have noticed this noise when PC shuts down. It is the same sound when I force shutdown by pressing power button for 5 seconds, so I am worried about that. Is it normal or maybe faulty motherboard? Thank you

https://soundcloud.com/luca-celeste-95225427/shut-down-noise/s-jmoG25JWy7C?utm_source=clipboard&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=social_sharing

Comment: What OS are you on? Try third-party Live Windows or Live Linux USB and try to shut down the system from that live OS and check if that sound again comes or not. Do you have an HDD?

Comment: I am on windows 11. Yes, it was an HDD making that sound. Thank you anyway for your contribution, it may be useful if the problem comes back for any reason (I don't trust completely of this motherboard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that DOES sound a bit rough, but I wouldn't say abnormal. It sounds like older PC's. I suspect the new motherboard has more capacitors or something that power is suddenly cutting off power whereas old motherboard wasn't the exact same. It also sounds like it could be a mechanical hard drive suddenly loosing power.

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly the sound of a mechanical hard drive that I forgot to disconnect. Now after shut down it emits a gentle "click" from the PSU, but seem much more normal. Maybe was the hard drive sound that made it a bit rough.

Comment: Glad you got it narrowed down. If this 'solved' your question you want to mark it as the accepted answer: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer